# Android expanded list item

Tags: android

How to change the color of groupItem in ExpandableListView when it is expanded?
And change to white color when it is not expanded?

Answer (score 0):

In your expandable list adapter you have one method called getGroupView(), by using that method you can do this.

```
 public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

      //Here you can initialize your view
      if(isExpanded){
        // set color for expanded item.
      }else{
       // set color for non expanded item.
      }
  }
```